# Show hidden span when input is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show a hidden span tag when an input is selected.  Multiple inputs will be present on the page and each one has its own hidden div showing the price.

I have tried using jQuery's .closest() and .find() but have not had any luck.  I know .closest() will work if it is within the parent element which seems like this should be the way to go but no success so far.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tm-extra-product-options-container">
    <ul data-rules="[]" data-rulestype="[]" data-tm-validation="[]" class="tmcp-ul-wrap tmcp-elements tm-extra-product-options-variations tm-variation-ul-radio variation-element-2">
        <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
            <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_0_0 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="12-x-48" id="tmcp_choice_2_0_0" tabindex="" type="radio">
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0"></label>
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0">
                <span class="tm-label">12 x 48</span>
            </label>
            <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">5.00</span>
        </li>
        <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
            <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_1_1 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-24" id="tmcp_choice_2_1_1" tabindex="" type="radio">
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1"></label>
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1">
                <span class="tm-label">24 x 24</span>
            </label>
            <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">6.00</span>
        </li>
        <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
            <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_2_2 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-36" id="tmcp_choice_2_2_2" tabindex="" type="radio">
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2"></label>
            <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2">
                <span class="tm-label">24 x 36</span>
            </label>
            <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">7.50</span>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('span.price').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Finally here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1fvpoj2/)

Comment: Use `siblings()`. [`$(this).siblings('span.price').fadeIn();`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vbLmshu3/)

Comment: wow, I had tried parents() but never occurred to me to try siblings, please post as answer so I can accept

Comment: If your interested in doing this with pure css, I would take a look at the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). Personally, I think this would be the cleanest way to go. You might have to adjust your markup slightly though.

Comment: Or the general sibling selector mentioned in @Tushar's answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` is not closest element of `input`, it is sibling of `input`. You can do it like following.

```
 $('input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('span.price').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use jQuery/JS** when the same can be achieved using CSS.

Use [CSS General Sibling Selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]:checked ~ span.price {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
span.price {
  display: none;
}
input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]:checked ~ span.price {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tm-extra-product-options-container">
  <ul data-rules="[]" data-rulestype="[]" data-tm-validation="[]" class="tmcp-ul-wrap tmcp-elements tm-extra-product-options-variations tm-variation-ul-radio variation-element-2">
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_0_0 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="12-x-48" id="tmcp_choice_2_0_0"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0">
        <span class="tm-label">12 x 48</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;">5.00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_1_1 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-24" id="tmcp_choice_2_1_1"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1">
        <span class="tm-label">24 x 24</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;">6.00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_2_2 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-36" id="tmcp_choice_2_2_2"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2">
        <span class="tm-label">24 x 36</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;">7.50</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**The problem is OP code** is that the `<span>` is the sibling element of the radio button. If you still want to use jQuery I've already provided solution in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694323/show-hidden-span-when-input-is-selected/34694425#comment57134591_34694323).

Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the sibling element.

```
$(this).siblings('span.price').fadeIn();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vbLmshu3/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('span.price').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tm-extra-product-options-container">
  <ul data-rules="[]" data-rulestype="[]" data-tm-validation="[]" class="tmcp-ul-wrap tmcp-elements tm-extra-product-options-variations tm-variation-ul-radio variation-element-2">
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_0_0 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="12-x-48" id="tmcp_choice_2_0_0"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_0_0">
        <span class="tm-label">12 x 48</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">5.00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_1_1 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-24" id="tmcp_choice_2_1_1"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_1_1">
        <span class="tm-label">24 x 24</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">6.00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tmhexcolorimage-li-nowh tm-per-row">
      <input class="tmcp-field  tm-epo-variation-element tmhexcolor_2_2_2 tm-epo-field tmcp-radio" name="tm_attribute_pa_size_2" data-price="" data-rules="" data-rulestype="" data-image="" data-imagep="" data-tm-for-variation="pa_size" value="24-x-36" id="tmcp_choice_2_2_2"
      tabindex="" type="radio">
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2"></label>
      <label for="tmcp_choice_2_2_2">
        <span class="tm-label">24 x 36</span>
      </label>
      <span class="pa_size price" id="varID-1" style="color:#29F938;font-weight:700;display:none;">7.50</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** This does not hide the text of the previous checked radio button. If you want to hide that, you can use following code.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uxvyLxc8/)

```
$('input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]').change(function () {
    // Hide text of other radio buttons
    $('span.price').fadeOut();

    $(this).siblings('span.price').fadeIn();
});
```

---

**Some Improvements:**

1. There are many attributes on the radio `<input>` which I suspect are not used. Those can be removed. Ex: `tabindex=""`
2. There are two `<label>` used for single radio, having same `for` attribute value. First of those, **an empty `label` can be removed**.
3. **ID should be unique**. Currently, same ID `varID-1` is used on all `span.price`.
4. Don't use **inline styles**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `siblings` instead. See this **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLmvc9np/)** for a demo.

```
$(this).siblings('span.price').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()` or `nextAll()`

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $('input[data-tm-for-variation="pa_size"]').change(function(){
                $(this).nextAll('span.price:first').fadeIn();
        });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/r1fvpoj2/1/